# Want to Avoid Sorting Full-Text Search Results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm using the following SQL Server query, which searches a full-text index and appears to be working correctly. Some additional work is included so the query works with paging.

However, my understanding is that full-text searches return results sorted according to ranking, which would be nice.

But I get an error if I remove the OVER clause near the top. Can anyone tell me how this query could be modified to not resort the results?

```
DECLARE @StartRow int;
DECLARE @MaxRows int;

SET @StartRow = 0;
SET @MaxRows = 10;

WITH ArtTemp AS
(SELECT TOP (@StartRow + @MaxRows) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ArtViews DESC) AS RowID,
Article.ArtID,Article.ArtTitle,Article.ArtSlug,Category.CatID,Category.CatTitle,
Article.ArtDescription,Article.ArtCreated,Article.ArtUpdated,Article.ArtUserID,
[User].UsrDisplayName AS UserName
FROM Article
INNER JOIN Subcategory ON Article.ArtSubcategoryID = Subcategory.SubID
INNER JOIN Category ON Subcategory.SubCatID = Category.CatID
INNER JOIN [User] ON Article.ArtUserID = [User].UsrID
WHERE CONTAINS(Article.*,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"htmltag")'))

SELECT ArtID,ArtTitle,ArtSlug,CatID,CatTitle,ArtDescription,ArtCreated,ArtUpdated,
ArtUserID,UserName
FROM ArtTemp
WHERE RowID BETWEEN @StartRow + 1 AND (@StartRow + @MaxRows)
ORDER BY RowID
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not an expert in FTS but hopefully this helps get you started.

First, `ROW_NUMBER` requires `OVER (ORDER BY xxx)` in SQL Server.  Even if you tell it to order by a constant value, it still *might* end up rearranging the results.  So, if you depend on row numbering to handle your pagination, you're stuck with some kind of sorting.

When I dig around on FTS for that "return results sorted according to ranking" bit, I find [a couple](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsearch/thread/b008c27f-6828-4249-ab01-067cf295acd2) [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) that describe ordering by rank.  In a nutshell, they say that `RANK` is a column explicitly returned by `CONTAINSTABLE`.  So if you can't find a way to dig out the results ranking from `CONTAINS`, you might try joining against `CONTAINSTABLE` instead and use the `RANK` column explicitly as your order by value with `ROW_NUMBER`.  Example (syntax may be a little off):

```
SELECT TOP (@StartRow + @MaxRows)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyFTS.RANK DESC) AS RowID,
    Article.ArtID,Article.ArtTitle,Article.ArtSlug,Category.CatID,Category.CatTitle,
    Article.ArtDescription,Article.ArtCreated,Article.ArtUpdated,Article.ArtUserID,
    [User].UsrDisplayName AS UserName
FROM Article
INNER JOIN Subcategory ON Article.ArtSubcategoryID = Subcategory.SubID
INNER JOIN Category ON Subcategory.SubCatID = Category.CatID
INNER JOIN [User] ON Article.ArtUserID = [User].UsrID
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Article, *, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"htmltag")') AS MyFTS
```

The end result is that you're still sorting, but you're doing so on your rankings.

Also, the MSDN page says that `CONTAINSTABLE` has an ability to limit results on a TOP *N* basis, too.  Maybe this would also be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks--perhaps you're correct and that is the best answer. However, I'm not sure I want the overhead of additional join and columns. Also, I noticed you eliminated the temporary table I had. Perhaps you just did that for testing? It seems to be necessary for paging logic.

Comment: You're correct - I only changed/showed the CTE. You do need the whole thing for paging.  As for the join overhead, you might not notice depending on your table width and indexes.  Either option involves the external FTS engine to hit your DB and send back some kind of per-row disposition anyway.  And some people find `CONTAINSTABLE` faster: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29849015/contains-vs-containstable-performance.aspx

Comment: Right on, CONTAINS is a boolean match, yes or no. So you're not really sorting on relevance at all.  Follow Matt's advice and use CONTAINSTABLE instead which will give you sortable RANK.